# WHERE clause in SQL statement is giving a syntax error when similar ones work fine

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, where-clause

So I'm working on HW and I can't figure out why I'm getting a syntax error in my sql query.

For some reason this doesn't work. company_name is a varchar.

```
SELECT customer.contact_name, order.order_id, order.completed, order.cancelled 
FROM mystudentID_customers customer, mystudentID_orders order 
WHERE customer.company_name = 'Rosas Bank' 
AND order.cust_id = customer.cust_id 
;
```

**And gives me this error:** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE customer.company_name = 'Rosas Bank'
AND order.cust_id = customer.cust_id' at line 3

**But I can run this just fine, I don't see how they are different and one works and another doesn't.**

```
SELECT employee.first_name, employee.state, customer.contact_name, customer.state 
FROM mystudentID_employees employee, mystudentID_empcust empcust, mystudentID_customers customer WHERE employee.emp_id = empcust.emp_id AND customer.cust_id = empcust.cust_id 
AND employee.state = customer.state 
;
```

**This also works**

```
Select customer.company_name 
FROM mystudentID_customers customer 
WHERE customer.company_name = 'Rosas Bank' 
;
```

I tried to do a smaller statement to check if I could actually do = "string" and it worked. I also googled the error and nothing similar is showing up.

Comment: `order` is a reserved word, it's part of `ORDER BY`, so use a different alias.

Comment: Since `order` is a reserved word, you may need to enclose it in back ticks.

Comment: Read the manual page for further explanation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html